# Non-matching records returned when using OR in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

On one model the query works, but for another it doesn't...

```
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array(
                                array( $model.'group_id' => array(2,3,4) ),
                                'OR' => array('name LIKE ' => "%$searchTerm%",
                                              'desc LIKE ' => "%$searchTerm%",
                                              'modified LIKE ' => "%$searchTerm%")));
```

I've tried without the group ids, just searchTerm and 'OR'. But, when I enter Foo I still get Bar and Baz as well. I check the table just in case Foo is contained in Bar/Baz somewhere, but it isn't. So my condition must be wrong....

OK, from debug this is the actual query, returning non-matching rows when searchTerm is Foo:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`pin`, `User`.`is_ldap`, `User`.`ldap_username`, `User`.`fullname`, `User`.`group_id`, `User`.`password_changed`, `User`.`last_login`, `User`.`status`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`parent_id`, `Group`.`lft`, `Group`.`rght`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`description`, `Group`.`status`, `Group`.`created`, `Group`.`modifed` FROM `crfsystem`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `crfsystem`.`groups` AS `Group` ON (`User`.`group_id` = `Group`.`id`) WHERE `User`.`group_id` IN (4, 5, 6, 7, 19, 16, 3) AND ((`User`.`username` LIKE '%foo%') OR (`User`.`is_ldap` LIKE '1') OR (`User`.`ldap_username` LIKE '%foo%') OR (`User`.`fullname` LIKE '%foo%') OR (`User`.`password_changed` LIKE '%foo%') OR (`User`.`last_login` LIKE '%foo%') OR (`User`.`status` LIKE '%foo%') OR (`User`.`created` LIKE '%foo%') OR (`User`.`modified` LIKE '%foo%'))
```

There are effectively 'two' conditions in WHERE as I understand:

```
A and (B or C or D ...)
```

So, return rows where A is true and (..) is true, right? But what is ....
***OH!*** I think I know... I need to ignore boolean fields because they eval to 1/True regardless of search term.

Comment: Pls share the final output query. set debug to 3 and see what is actual query.

Comment: debug 2 suffices ;) but the array looks good to me. should be working. maybe there is no data that matches?

Comment: Should be blank then right?  I've copied the query from debug and pasted in phpmyadmin and messing with it there, just using the OR conditions.  Still additional non-matching rows are returned. >_<

Comment: Ok manipulating the query, it seems certain fields are triggering it. When I just have two fields in the OR Like just Foo is returned as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array(
        $model.'group_id' => array(2,3,4),
        'OR' => array(
            array('name LIKE ' => "%$searchTerm%"), 
            array('desc LIKE ' => "%$searchTerm%"), 
            array('modified LIKE ' => "%$searchTerm%")
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do LIKE '%searchTerm%' with a boolean field it evaluates to true so those rows will be returned!